# Sprite kit- Cannot change the colour of text (always white)

Tags: text, ios7, sprite-kit

I am writing a 2d game in sprite kit and I am creating the menu screen. Everything is ok so far apart from the fact that the text always appears white, whatever values of red, green, blue etc that I enter into the code. This is the code that I am using to create the background for the menu:

```
-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size
{
if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {

    NSLog(@"Size: %@", NSStringFromCGSize(size));
    [self setBackgroundColor:[SKColor colorWithRed:0.9 green:0.9 blue:0.9 alpha:1.0]];

    self.writing = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"Thonburi Bold"];
    self.writing.text = @"MAIN MENU";
    self.writing.fontSize = 42;
    self.writing.color = [SKColor colorWithRed:0.1 green:0.1 blue:0.1 alpha:1.0];
    self.writing.position = CGPointMake(130, 270);
    [self addChild:self.writing];
}
return  self;
```

}

I have other code in the project and I checked that none of it is anything to do with the colour of the text on this screen.

(I am new to programming so this might be a fairly obvious mistake)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `color` property is the blend color. You want to use `fontColor` to change the text's color.

```
label.fontColor = [SKColor colorWithRed:0.1 green:1 blue:0.1 alpha:1.0];
```

You could also use `color` and set `colorBlendFactor` to 1. Though this might be slower depending on how it's handled internally.

Comment: Thanks, it fixed the problem. Knew it would be something simple :)

Comment: The use of the .color attribute worked up through iOS8 to set the text color, but no longer works in iOS 9. You must use the .fontColor attribute to set the color of the text.